# Is there a way to generate a graph of specified treewidth

Tags: computational-complexity, random-graphs, trees

The treewidth is a parameter of the graph that describes its similarity to a tree. Treewidth is NP-hard to find. For the introduction please see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth)

The question is how to generate interesting graphs with a specified treewidth? I know that:
1) Any graph containing a $k+1$-clique has treewidth at least $k$
2) Any graph containing a $k \times k$ grid has treewidth at least $k$

Are other variants possible?

Comment: $k$-trees can be generated incrementally by definition. Subgraphs that are not too sparse (e.g., leave at least one $(k+1)$-clique intact) also have treewidth $k$. Generating w.r. uniform measure among graphs of treewidth $k$ seems hard.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Having an intact $k+1$-clique in the graph is another option which is also not very interesting. However, is it possible to remove some edges from the clique so the treewidth is still $k$? I corrected the original question to mention the large clique case. I would like to generate hard cases to test the tree decomposition algorithm

Comment: An interesting test would be to distinguish between a full $k$-tree (treewidth $k$) and and a full $k$-tree with an extra random edge (treewidth $k + 1$). You may also want to look up critical forbidden minor tables for small $k$ (can't quite find the link myself right now).

Comment: Thanks for this idea! It looks the modification of the $k$-tree is the route to take. Also, I found some results on the structure of the treewidth-$k$ graphs which do not contain a $k \times k$-grid as a minor here:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.6927.pdf

I would accept your comment as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an extended comment. Here are some classes of graphs that should be interesting:

- $k$-trees by definition have treewidth $k$; moreover, adding any edge to a $k$-tree increases treewidth. This should be an interesting example since $k$-trees are "borderline maximal" with treewidth $k$.
- Graphs with treewdith $\leq k$ are [famously characterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth#Forbidden_minors) by a finite set of forbidden minors. Each of these minors is again interesting since they are "borderline minimal" with treewidth $> k$. Again, deleting any edge from any such critical graph decreases treewidth.
- Edge subdivision does not change treewidth, hence any interesting graph can be artificially "inflated" to produce another, sparser one.

Answer (score 0):

Graphs of bounded treewidth may be defined by forbidden induced subgraphs.

Examples are on [graphclasses.org](http://graphclasses.org/classes/par_10.html)